# Need help with the combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Allow me to ask (may be a silly) question, I got my school exam tommorow and I'm stuck in a question. (Orignal question is different)

There is a bag with 9 balls including 3 blue , 2 red , 4 black balls. Balls of same color are non identical, we have to select 4 balls such that there must be atleast a ball of each color. 
I deduce answer from original question to be 144. 
And I did get 144
It went like 
Selecting one ball of each color amd then selecting 1 ball from left 6 balls.
$$^4 C_1 × ^3 C_1× ^2 C_1× ^6 C_1$$ which gives 144.
If the above math doesn't look the way I expected, then it is
4C1 × 3C1× 2C1 ×6C1

But, what confuses me is, 
I made 3 cases.
First selected 2 balls from blue , one each from rest two, then did the same 3 times with other colors. Which added upto 72.

Answer should be 144.
I don't know where I am lacking, is it a conceptual error?

Comment: One downvote immediately, question has to be silly

Comment: I don't think it is silly.   Let's just look at each case.  Two blues:  $3\times 2\times 4=24$.  Two reds: $3\times 4=12$.  Two blacks: $3\times 2\times 6=36$  The total is $72$.  The other answer, $144$, doesn't even makes sense...if we ignore the colors completely, $\binom 94=126$ so the answer must be considerably smaller than that.

Comment: The method you used to get $144$ double counts.  The choices: $(B_1,R_1,b_1,B_2)$ and $(B_2,R_1,b_1,B_1)$ are the same selection...so you just have to divide by $2$.

Comment: Thanks, for that double count information.... offical answers could get wrong is what I learn

Comment: Good instincts by the way, to look for alternate methods.  These problems can be very unintuitive, so it's a great idea to have many ways of looking at them.

Comment: As yet another way to approach the problem, try Inclusion-Exclusion.  There are $126$ choices if we ignore color...how many of those are missing blue?  red? black?  How many are missing two colors?